# passport node adding a parameter

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

When I use passport coinbase for node

```
passport.use(new CoinbaseStrategy({
    clientID: COINBASE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: COINBASE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/coinbase/callback",
    scope: [ "send" ] ,

  },
```

I get the error

> Invalid amount for `meta[send_limit_amount]` ()

What is the syntax for adding this parameter? I tried like 10 different things.

Answer (score 0):

The passport-coinbase library does not recognise meta data 
However there is a callback function in passport itself that will pick up any additional authorisation parameters

I added this just after my `passport.use(...)` to get things moving again

// we have to handle metadata ourselves

```
const metaData = { 
    send_limit_amount : 50, 
    send_limit_currency : 'USD', 
    send_limit_period : 'day' 
};
passport._strategies.coinbase.authorizationParams = function(options) {     
    var meta = {};
    for(o in metaData){
        meta['meta['+o+']'] = metaData[o]; 
    };
    return meta;
};
```